# Cannot use token from localstorage in React

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have the below code where I am storing userId and token in localStorage. When I refresh the page /admin I still always get redirected to /login, as if I'm not logged in.

'userData' is stored in localStorage with the keys 'userId' and 'token'.

Initial login also works, only when I refresh, I get back to the login page.

What am I missing?

```js
const App = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(false);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(false);

  const login = useCallback((uid, token) => {
    setToken(token);
    setUserId(uid);
    localStorage.setItem(
      "userData",
      JSON.stringify({ userId: uid, token: token })
    );
  }, []);

  const logout = useCallback(() => {
    setToken(null);
    setUserId(null);
    localStorage.removeItem("userData");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
    if (storedData && storedData.token) {
      console.log(`storedData.userId: ${storedData.userId}`);
      console.log(`storedData.token: ${storedData.token}`);
      login(storedData.userId, storedData.token);
    }
  }, [login]);

  let routes;

  console.log(`isLoggedIn: ${token}`);

  if (token) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin">
          <Admin />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/admin" />
      </Switch>
    );
  } else {
    routes = (
      <Switch>        
        <Route path="/map">
          <Map />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        isLoggedIn: !!token,
        token: token,
        userId: userId,
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
      }}
    >
      <Router>
        <main>{routes}</main>
      </Router>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: if you look in the local storage, do you see the token and id?

Comment: yes that part works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are checking if the token is true:

```
 if (token) {
routes = (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/admin">
      <Admin />
    </Route>
    <Redirect to="/admin" />
  </Switch>
);
 } else {
routes = (
  <Switch>        
    <Route path="/map">
      <Map />
    </Route>
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  </Switch>
  );
}
```

But the token is stored in a state variable, which indeed is a Javascript variable and every time you reload the page, all Javascript variables are wiped up and your component starts a new lifecycle. So, when you reach out the token verification section to return the routes, turns out that token is false because variables were wiped up and you are initializing the token state to false:

```
const [token, setToken] = useState(false);
```

What you could do is checking if the token exists in localStorage during first render cycle (useEffect with empty array argument) and set token to true if it exists.

Comment: I did add a useEffect with an empty array that checks localstorage and sets the token (setToken) but it still doesn't work. Same behaviour as in my initial description.

Comment: can you update the question to add the new code or a stackblitz link?

Comment: you could also init the token state with the value in LocalStorage.

Comment: wow, nice ! the answer I was looking for!